# Can I do anything outside of bounty to improve getting responses to my question on potential contractor fraud?

Tags: discussion

My [most recent question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/184754/how-to-investigate-contractor-under-a-fraudulent-identity-without-tipping-them-o) only has 2 responses so far despite close to 600 views and was posted several days ago.

It was not quickly closed as violating a SE rule (rant , legal advice request etc). I feel I have provided sufficient details and responded to questions by commenters.

Other than opening a bounty, which I did now, how else can I get more detailed answers here?

Comment: There is few things you can do now... To get more detailed answers (besides offering bounty specifying that), only time will yield more/better answers... perhaps you have few answers because few users are knowledgeable on the subject, as to be capable of offering an answer... finally, I see you are asking legal-related stuff, something that's also hard to get a good answer from random folks on the internet, and perhaps better suited to contact a lawyer instead

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because once you mention sanctions lists you're entering a very small niche of specialised and highly regulated territory with extreme penalties if procedures are not followed correctly. A year or two ago a large bank in Australia got fined 2 billion just for not following procedures properly as I recall.

So if there are professionals who deal with that here they can only give the same answer that has already been given. There are no other viable options in the context given.

The fact that it's several days may mean that your company is already in breach of reporting mandates and wide open to serious repercussions depending on your locale.